# X11 windows created by root

Tags: security, xorg

Do windows created by root processes have any special privileges in X11? The X server and the window manager was created by a regular user process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure that you understand the difference between the X11 window and the process that runs in that window.

For the window itself, see the answer of user414777. The process that creates the window (for example `xterm`) will have additional privileges when run as root.

However, note the differences:

`xterm -e bash` gives an xterm window with `bash`. Both `bash` and `xterm` run under your own UID.

`sudo xterm -e bash` will also create a window with `bash`, but now `xterm` and `bash` run as root.

`xterm -e sudo bash` creates again a window with `bash`, but now `xterm`runs under your own UID and `bash` runs as root.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

And if you're actually meaning X11 *clients* instead of X11 windows, it's still **No**.

There isn't any concept of privileged X11 clients, they're all equal, and they all have access to any X11 resource.

Any client can do any action on any window, including drawing on it or changing its properties (like its title or icon). Any client can grab the keyboard or the mouse. Any client can fake keyboard or mouse input with the XTest extension.

And any client can kick out another client with `XKillClient(3)` (not related to the Unix `kill(2)` system call).